# createAsyncThunk action always rejected

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

Hi i have a problem with createAsyncThunk, i have started a json-server with json document in it.
i'm tryng to dispatch the action getTodos but the action is always rejected and i do not why.
i'm sure the server is working properly because i testes it with postman, any one can help me?

```
    import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    import { filterTodo } from "./FilterSlice";
    
// the url are deleted for privacy
    const urlTodos = "";
    const urlFilter = "";
    
    
    export const getTodos = createAsyncThunk(
      "todos/getTodos",
      async (data = null, thunkAPI) => {
     
        const todosPromise = fetch(urlTodos)
          .then((resp) => resp.json())
          .then((res) => res);
    
        console.log("todoPromise", typeof todosPromise);
    
        const filterPromise = fetch(urlFilter)
          .then((resp) => resp.json())
          .then((res) => res);
    
    
        let [todos, activeFilter] = await Promise.all([
          todosPromise,
          filterPromise,
        ]);
        
        thunkAPI.dispatch(filterTodo(activeFilter));
        return todos;
      }
    );
    
    export const todosSlice = createSlice({
      name: "todos", // nome della slice
      initialState: [],
      reducers: {
        addTodo(state, action) {
          console.log("add todo");
          state.push(action.payload);
        },
    
        removeTodo(state, action) {
          state = state.filter((todo) => todo.name !== action.payload.name);
          return state;
        },
    
        toggleTodo(state, action) {
          state = state.map(function (todo) {
            if (todo.id === action.payload.id) {
              todo.completed = !todo.completed;
            }
          });
        },
      },
    
      extraReducers: (builder) => {
        // reducer che gestisce la pending action
        builder
          .addCase(getTodos.pending, (state, actions) => {
            state.status = "loading";
            console.log("in pending");
          })
          .addCase(getTodos.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.status = "success";
            console.log("in getTodos fulfilled", action.payload);
            state = action.payload;
            return state;
          })
    
          .addCase(getTodos.rejected, (state, action) => {
            console.log("in getTodos rejected", action.payload);
          });
      },
    });
    const { actions, reducer } = todosSlice;
    
    export const { addTodo, removeTodo, toggleTodo } = actions;
    
    export default reducer;
```

it was dispatched in the following way

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    
    console.log("dentro use effect");
    dispatch(getTodos());

    return () => {};
  }, [dispatch]);
```

and the structure of the json object is the following

```
{
  "todos": [
    {
      "completed": true,
      "name": "Call my mum",
      "dueDate": "17/3/2022",
      "user_id": 1,
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "completed": false,
      "name": "go to school",
      "dueDate": "17/3/2022",
      "user_id": 2,
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "completed": true,
      "name": "do homework",
      "dueDate": "17/3/2022",
      "user_id": 3,
      "id": 3
    }
  ],
  "filter": ["ALL"]
}
```

this is what appen when i try to excute the program
[image]

the console is that
[image]

the redux extension of chrome reports this error
[image]

Comment: Check the console if there is some logs/errors and share it in your question, it can be helpful to debug the problem

Comment: i add the console's screenshot but there aren't any errors

Answer (score 0):

i found the error:

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
          .addCase(getTodos.pending, (state, actions) => {
            console.log("in pending");
          })
          .addCase(getTodos.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            console.log("in getTodos fulfilled", action.payload);
            state = action.payload;
            return state;
          })
    
          .addCase(getTodos.rejected, (state, action) => {
            console.log("in getTodos rejected", action.payload);
          });
      },
    });
```

i removed the state.status = string and now it works